# Print value from a DataFrame (wrong output, need only 1 item from a DataFrame)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `for` loop going to find all matching values from two DataFrames.
List is read:

```
 for index, row in output_merged_po.iterrows():
    stock = output_merged_stock[output_merged_stock['PN_STRIPPED'] == row['PN_STRIPPED']][['Whs']]
    print stock
```

In which I get results when PN matches:

```
         WHS    
111      VKO     
1111     VKO
1112     ZZZ
```

So if I put

```
if stock.iloc[0:3]['Whs'].values[0] == '_':
   print stock
```

or

```
if any(stock['Whs'] == 'VNO'):
    print stock
```

I get result as above:

```
         WHS    
111      VKO     
1111     VKO
1112     ZZZ
```

Where i need only see 111 and 1111 lines where WHS is VKO.

However, if I write second Whs name to look for (ZZZ):

```
if stock.iloc[0:3]['Whs'].values[0] == 'ZZZ':
    print stock
```

I get empty line, no info is printed, while i want to see

```
          Whs
1112      ZZZ
```

To be printed.

How it is possible to solve that problem and see only a line/lines which are needed to see?

Comment: So first of all, `stock`, from what I can tell, is a pandas DataFrame (Why would you not mention that in your question).  Second of all, any time you run `print stock` it is going to print the entire DataFrame. I think you need to take some time and learn how to properly index pandas DataFrames and then edit your quesiton.  Here is a link to the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html

Comment: I think you're confusing how to filter here, if you're looking for a specific value then `stock[stock['Whs'] == 'VKO']` will return only the rows where that condition is satisfied, for your last part the reason you get an empty row is that you're slicing the first 3 rows and then comparing the first value with your string but the first string value is 'VKO' and not 'ZZZ', you should do this: `stock[stock['Whs'] == 'ZZZ']` to filter the resuls first

Comment: EdChum, stock[stock['Whs'] == 'ZZZ'] did not work... I get again message:  ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().